# Consulta general sobre MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy acostumbrado a utilizar Sql Server Express para mis proyectos de forma local, para que funcione siempre instalo el servidor en el mismo pc y en la conexión le paso en server un "." (localhost) y todo funciona perfecto. El tema que ahora quiero cambiar a MySql de forma local también ( tengan en cuenta que desde mis proyectos accedo a la base de datos muchas veces o sea debe tener la posibilidad de multi instancias a la base de datos ).

Mi consulta es: Que debo instalar en la maquina de mis clientes para que funcione MySql de forma local? ej.: con Sql Server Express instalo el sql obviamente donde en la instalacion le paso las rutas de las db, el nombre de la instancia, el password, la configuracion en cortafuegos de windows y todo anda perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

entiendo que es el mismo método, podés instalar el MySQL en el equipo local de tu cliente, o si tenés la base en otro equipo de la red, hacer la instalacion y configurar las conexiones en tu aplicación. No hay mucha diferencia con otros motores en ese sentido, no se si respondo correctamente a tu consulta.

Comment: Si, gracias. En mi caso no uso red, solo para 1 pc. Tal vez existía algún método para evitar la instalación de mysql en el pc

Comment: Bueno, existe tambien SQLite, que no necesita instalación, pero eso depende del tipo de aplicación que tenés, podés fijarte en esta comparación sobre motores en donde indican ventajas y desventajas de uno y otro, https://www.capterra.es/blog/639/software-base-de-datos-gratuitos-codigo-abierto

Comment: Por lo que he leído SQLite no admite consultas simultaneas. y lo peor de todo es que solo utilizo 2 tablas donde no tienen mas de 20 registros